# Gottemeitschi is from which German language?

Tags: english-to-german, pronoun, person-names, proper-noun, swiss-german

Gottemeitschi means godmother, but in which German dialect and region? What is the masculine form, plus granduncle, grand aunt, etc? And how do they compare to their high German, or formal, counterparts?

This question was asked because translators did not recognize the word Gottemeitschi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I speak the language, *Gottemeitschi* means *goddaughter*. *Meitschi* is a Term for *Mädchen* (*Girl*) commonly and specifically used around Bern. Most Swiss German speakers in northeastern Switzerland would say *Gottemeitli* instead.

The term *Göttibueb* is used for *godson*, *Götti* for *godfather* and *Gotte* for *godmother*.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that in a Swiss dialect *Gottemeitschi* actually means goddaughter, although i don't have a reliable source besides a [blog page.](https://www.bluesler.ch/gotte-und-gottemeitschi/)